# How to send a list of values one by one to call a single method

Tags: angular, typescript

Here i am getting the below dynamic data from the server

```
{
"Data": [
{
"LocationId": 6,
"LocationName": "J",
},
{
"LocationId": 3,
"LocationName": "M",

},
{
"LocationId": 2,
"LocationName": "P",
},
{
"LocationId": 5,
"LocationName": "B",
},
{
"LocationId": 4,
"LocationName": "D",

}
],
"ErrorCode": "201 - Success",
"Message": "Success",
"Status": true
}
```

and by using the above data i am looping in template and ,displaying it in the div dynamically

```
<div class="card"  *ngFor="let location of locationsName">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{location.LocationName |uppercase}}</h5>
    <h5 class="card-title" hidden>{{location.LocationId}}</h5>

  </div>
```

here my issue is  by using  locationids values how can i call another service/method here i have 1,2,4,5,6 as locationids. In the  below service i have to send only 1 paramter so at a time how can i send all the values and get result and display in the same div

```
this.serv.getOrder(this.locationId).subscribe(res=>{
      this.OrdersData = res.Data;

    });
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are trying to order the array by each location ID, is that right or could you give more details about what you want to archive?

Comment: i am displaying the the location values 1,2,6,5,4 dynamically in the form of Div that means 5 separate div and by using the above value i have to call another service method so that it will get another data and i had to display it in the same div.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous comment about bad practice, your backend should return all needed data in order to increase performance.

However, if you are unable to update backend or you have other reasons that implies new calls from the UI, you should first loop through the `locationsName` array and, on each iteration, call the service to fetch data. Then append it to the current object of the iteration.

Pass the individual object of `locationsName` array to the service:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.locationsName.length; i++) {
   this.serv.getOrder(this.locationsName[i]).subscribe(res=>{
     // Here add new properties to objects
     this.locationsName[i]['OrdersData'] = res.Data;
   });
}
```

The *ngFor items will update upon fetching results from the backend, as Angular triggers change detection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
locationsName: any;
locationData: any;
locationsNameNew: any = [];
constructor() {
    this.locationsName = [
        {
            "LocationId": 6,
            "LocationName": "J",
        },
        {
            "LocationId": 3,
            "LocationName": "M",

        },
        {
            "LocationId": 2,
            "LocationName": "P",
        },
        {
            "LocationId": 5,
            "LocationName": "B",
        },
        {
            "LocationId": 4,
            "LocationName": "D",

        }
    ]
}

ngOnInit() {
    for (let locationsNameObj of this.locationsName) {
        var newValue = this.method1(locationsNameObj.LocationId);  // The service method which you want to call
        this.locationData = {
            'LocationId': locationsNameObj.LocationId,
            'LocationName': locationsNameObj.LocationName,
            'newLocationId': newValue
        };
        this.locationsNameNew.push(this.locationData); // New response Object
    }
}

public method1(LocationId: any) {
    var LocationIdDummy = LocationId+1;   // the new values which u obtained in Service
    return LocationIdDummy;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="card"  *ngFor="let location of locationsNameNew">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{location.LocationName |uppercase}}</h5>
    <h5 class="card-title" hidden>{{location.LocationId}}</h5>
    <h5 class="card-title">{{location.newLocationId}}</h5>

  </div>
```